# How can I get the average of a value in an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In this code I have a Doctor document and inside the document there is
an array of the doctor's patients .In this case I would like to find out the average age of all patients in my array.How could I do that?

```
  {
            "_id" : ObjectId("57113238bde91693e9ff69e7"),
            "docname" : "Arthur Hovsepyan",
            "job_desc" : "Hepatologist",
            "sex" : "male",
            "jobtype" : "fulltime",
            "office" : "room 448",
            "email" : "arturchik@hotmail.com",
            "phone_number" : 862124343,
            "address" : "68 Peterburg street,waterford",
            "hours" : 12,
            "patients" : [
                    {
                            "name" : "Jenny Power",
                            "ward_no" : 1,
                            "sex" : "female",
                            "termdays" : 2,
                            "illness_type" : "minor",
                            "age" : 22,
                            "phone_number" : 877285221,
                            "address" : "63 Johnston street ,Waterford"
                    },
                    {
                            "name" : "Marie Peters",
                            "ward_no" : 2,
                            "sex" : "female",
                            "termdays" : 0,
                            "illness_type" : "minor",
                            "age" : 21,
                            "phone_number" : 862145992,
                            "address" : "99 Grange,Waterford"
                    },
                    {
                            "name" : "Philip John",
                            "ward_no" : 2,
                            "sex" : "male",
                            "termdays" : 10,
                            "illness_type" : "serious",
                            "age" : 31,
                            "phone_number" : 861125981,
                            "address" : "12 Monvoy Bridge,Waterford"
                    },
                    {
                            "name" : "Marta Peters",
                            "ward_no" : 3,
                            "sex" : "female",
                            "termd7ays" : 0,
                            "illness_type" : "minor",
                            "age" : 31,
                            "phone_number" : 862125981,
                            "address" : "100 Grange Manor,Waterford"
                    }
            ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) method which provides access to the aggregation pipeline. That being said the optimal way to this is using the [`$avg`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/avg/#use-in-project-stage) accumulator operator in the [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage if you are using MongoDB 3.2 or newer.

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$project": { 
        "averageAge": { "$avg": "$patients.age" } 
    }}
])
```

---

From MongoDB 3.0 backwards you need a different approach. You can first `$project` your documents and return an array of "age" of your "patients" using the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) operator. From there you will need to de-normalize that array using the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operator then [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) your documents by `_id` and use the `$avg` operator to return the average of "age".

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$project": { 
        "agePatients": { 
            "$map": { 
                "input": "$patients", 
                "as": "p",
                "in": "$$p.age" 
            } 
        } 
    }}, 
    { "$unwind": "$agePatients" }, 
    { "$group": { 
        "_id":  "$_id", 
        "averageAge": { "$avg": "$agePatients" } 
    }} 
])
```

Which returns:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57113238bde91693e9ff69e7"), 
    "averageAge" : 26.25 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For this problem you will have to unwind the internal array of patients first and then apply the **$avg** operator on **patients.age** attribute. Your query would be :-

```
db. collection.aggregate([
    {
    "$unwind": "$patients"
    },  
    {
        $group : {
                _id:{
                        "docname" : "$docname"
                    },
                avg_age : {$avg : "$patients.age"}
             }

        }
])
```

Comment: when I try that I get an average of zero

Answer (score 0):

If you have MongoDB 3.2+, you can use `$avg` in `$project` stage which put less strain on server resources. However, if your MongoDB version is less than 3.2, consider solution posted by `ashisahu`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project:{
      docname: 1,
      job_desc: 1,
      sex: 1,
      jobtype: 1,
      office: 1,
      email: 1,
      phone_number: 1,
      address: 1,
      hours: 1,
      patients: 1,
      avg_age_of_patients:{$avg:"$patients.age"}
     }
   }
])
```

This will output following document. (see `avg_age_of_patients` field)

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57113238bde91693e9ff69e7"), 
    "docname" : "Arthur Hovsepyan", 
    "job_desc" : "Hepatologist", 
    "sex" : "male", 
    "jobtype" : "fulltime", 
    "office" : "room 448", 
    "email" : "arturchik@hotmail.com", 
    "phone_number" : 8.62124343E8, 
    "address" : "68 Peterburg street,waterford", 
    "hours" : 12.0, 
    "patients" : [
        {
            "name" : "Jenny Power", 
            "ward_no" : 1.0, 
            "sex" : "female", 
            "termdays" : 2.0, 
            "illness_type" : "minor", 
            "age" : 22.0, 
            "phone_number" : 8.77285221E8, 
            "address" : "63 Johnston street ,Waterford"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Marie Peters", 
            "ward_no" : 2.0, 
            "sex" : "female", 
            "termdays" : 0.0, 
            "illness_type" : "minor", 
            "age" : 21.0, 
            "phone_number" : 8.62145992E8, 
            "address" : "99 Grange,Waterford"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Philip John", 
            "ward_no" : 2.0, 
            "sex" : "male", 
            "termdays" : 10.0, 
            "illness_type" : "serious", 
            "age" : 31.0, 
            "phone_number" : 8.61125981E8, 
            "address" : "12 Monvoy Bridge,Waterford"
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Marta Peters", 
            "ward_no" : 3.0, 
            "sex" : "female", 
            "termd7ays" : 0.0, 
            "illness_type" : "minor", 
            "age" : 31.0, 
            "phone_number" : 8.62125981E8, 
            "address" : "100 Grange Manor,Waterford"
        }
    ], 
    "avg_age_of_patients" : 26.25
}
```